# How do I pass a value to another file, which is itself imported in current file?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-import

I have two files, one containing the tkinter code and another containing a function. I have a button in the tkinter window and an `Entry` field. I am trying to execute the function when clicking the button, but it needs the text from the `Entry` field to work. I get an error when trying to import anything from the tkinter file:

tkinter_file.py:

```
import File
window = Tk()
def input():
    s = entry1.get()
    return s

entry1 = Entry(window)
button1 = Button(window, text='GO', command=File.function)
```

File.py:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter_file

def function():
    req_url = 'http://someurl.com/{}'.format(tkinter_file.input)
    requests get url etc. etc.
```

I seem to be getting an error as soon as I import the `tkinter_file` into `File.py`, or even just the function `input`:

```
File "/etc/etc/tkinter_file.py", line 75, in <module>
button1 = Button(window, text='GO', command=File.function)
AttributeError: module 'File' has no attribute 'function'
```

I'm thinking that `req_url` not having the value `s` straight away is the problem, as well as maybe importing the 2 files into each other, but how do you overcome this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have two modules, say `a.py` and `b.py`, you can't import module `b` in `a` and then import module `a` in `b`, because that creates a **cyclic** dependency, which can't clearly be solved!

A solution would be to pass as parameter to `File.function` what you need for that function to run properly, i.e. the contents of the `entry1`.

```
button1 = Button(window, text='GO', command=lambda: File.function(entry1.get()))
```